# iOS - programmatically cancel all sounds/music?

Tags: ios, audio, sprite-kit

I am developing an iPhone game using Xcode's sprite kit and was wondering if there is a simple or best-practice method of canceling all sound-effects/ music programatically? The most obvious method to me is to create some boolean variable "isSoundAllowed" and set it to true/false when the user toggles sound on/off in my game, but I'd like to learn better techniques if available. Thanks!

P.S: the following is 1) the sound and 2) the music:

1)

```
_ActionExplodeSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"explosion.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
```

2)

```
-(void)playBackgroundMusic
{
NSError *error;
NSURL *backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"backgroundMusic.mp3" withExtension:nil];
_backgroundMusicPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
_backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[_backgroundMusicPlayer play];
}
```

edit: actually I can use [_backgroundMusicPlayer stop]; to stop the music, but is there a simple way like this to disable all sound effects (I have more than i list in #1 but they are of the same type)?

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far is this, but I'm confident there is a better/more compact of doing this:

```
-(void)toggleSound
{
BoolSoundEnabled=!BoolSoundEnabled;
if (BoolSoundEnabled==TRUE) {
    _ActionExplodeSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"explosion.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer play];
} else if (BoolSoundEnabled==FALSE) {
    _ActionExplodeSound=Nil ;
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer stop];
}

}
```